# How do I remove duplicates in a Linked HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm creating a Linked HashMap that will read a string and integer from the user inputs. It is set up like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> wordIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

My goal is to remove any duplicates the user may enter. Here is an example:

```
wordIndex.put("The", 0);
wordIndex.put("Hello", 6);
wordIndex.put("Katherine", 17);
wordIndex.put("Hello", 21);
```

I want to keep the first "Hello" and remove the second one.

This is my first time using Linked HashMaps, and thus, I am unfamiliar with the built-in functions that are at my disposal. Is there a function for HashMaps that can allow me to check the wordIndex HashMap one by one to look for duplicates every time a new value & key is entered? If not, what process can I use to check for duplicates individually? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are no duplicates in a `Map` by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior will `Override` the existing value with the existing `key`, So in the LinkedHashMap has the following values

```
{The=0, Hello=21, Katherine=17}
```

, And you can check if the `key` is already exists using `containsKey()`

```
if (wordIndex.containsKey("Hello")) {
    // do something        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is just the method I was looking for!

Comment: @WJS's solution is more concise.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I want to keep the first "Hello" and remove the second one.

To prevent the second entry attempt from overwriting the first entry in a `Map`, use [`Map::putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)) in Java 8 and later.

```
Map<String, Integer> wordIndex = new LinkedHashMap<>();
wordIndex.putIfAbsent("The", 0);
wordIndex.putIfAbsent("Hello", 6);
wordIndex.putIfAbsent("Katherine", 17);
wordIndex.putIfAbsent("Hello", 21);

wordIndex.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
The=0
Hello=6
Katherine=17
```

The `Map.putIfAbsent` will only the first values entered will be retained. We can see the first `("Hello", 6)` entry survived, and the second `("Hello", 21)` entry attempt failed and was discarded.

Comment: I made an edit to add a quote from the Question, and rephrase your text, to point out how your Answer is correct. Hopefully, this will prevent any further down-votes.

Comment: @BasilBourque I appreciate that. I don't understand why so many folks are quick to downvote. I got caught up in the question and also used the term "remove".  And you really aren't removing anything since maps can't have duplicates.  That is why I was downvoted.

Comment: In my experience, (a) there is quite often an explicable reflex to down-vote without much thought, and (b) some down-votes simply make no sense at all, such as a down-vote arriving after a couple dozen up-votes on an *accepted* answer — I call these "drive-by down-votes". Perhaps a sort of vandalization, or perhaps just an errant mouse-click/touch-tap.

Comment: If you are > 10k, you should be beyond caring about inexplicable downvotes.  :-)

Comment: @StephenC You're right of course.  But it's not about the rep but a matter of principle and the desire to correct a mistake.